# How can I get my Lubuntu system to "beep" via bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, motherboard, shell-script, xterm

Running Lubuntu 20.04LTS, and trying to get a nice beep when a bash script finishes.

Before anyone votes this down, I have tried:

```
beep
```

and

```
sudo modprobe snd-pcsp
```

and

```
say
```

and

```
echo -en "\007"
```

and

```
^G
```

and

```
printf '\a'
```

and

```
echo -e  "\033[11;1000]\a"
```

and

```
echo -e  "\033[10;1000]\a"
```

and

```
echo -en '\a'
```

and at this point, I'm pretty frustrated.  All I want is to have a nice loud "beep" at the end of a shell script so that when it's done, I'll hear it's finished.

Beep returns an error:  "open(): No such file or directory" The "say" command works but it's very soft and garbled and digitized speech and I really just want a nice beep.  Old school style, circa you-hit-the-wrong-key-on-your-Tandy-1000-back-in-1975.

Seems this cannot, cannot possibly be as hard, but everything I've tried thus far seems to be 11 years old with very little new info.  Maybe "beep"s are just gone?  I suspect (but am not sure) that the issue is I'm within Lubuntu, using a terminal, rather than at an actual terminal.  But beyond that...I'm just lost.

Thanks in advance to anyone who wants to help.  I can, if I have to, work with the "say" which does seem to work.  But I just want a nice loud beep if possible.  Am I asking for the moon?

Comment: Be very careful of this - when I last forced a beep in a script (SunOS4 - sh), nothing happened.  All the beeps were accumulated and the  the OS flushed them when the buffer was full.  This gave a continuous beep that lasted a few minutes and could not be stopped.  You have to make sure the output buffer is flushed after each beep.

Comment: Have a look at the answers in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1974/163144

Comment: Hahaha, @cup, thank you for the heads up.  It wouldn't surprise me if that happens.  Yeeesh.

Comment: But, @cup, yes, I started at this thread but it was 11 years ago.  And nothing in there seems to be working.

Comment: I tried something similar on windows in Powershell and basically ran into the same issues. One issue was that I assumed it was possible but that particular system did not seem to have a pc speaker at all. Another was that it did work but was very soft and a third was that it only worked if I did two beeps in a row because for some odd reason the beep expired before being played so I never heard it. I settled for using the OS sound system instead, going over normal speakers.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the answer was to give up and try something else: the "aplay" command.

I got a .wav file of a sound I liked, and all it required was:

```
aplay path/to/my/file.wav
```

And it worked great.  I wish I'd gotten the "beep" command to work but if you just want a bash script to play an alert, this was by far the easiest way to go.  No clue if it will help or work for others, but it was what I needed.